# Select2 bad positioning when dropdown doesn't fit in reamining container height

Tags: jquery-select2

I have this problem with the selec2 plugin where the drop down position it's not aligned with the select. (too bad I can't post pictures, no reputation points, I'll use my imagination:)

The way it looks:

```
  |--------Dropdown------|
     |-------Select--------|
```

The way it should look:

```
     |--------Dropdown-----|
     |-------Select--------|
```

(The dropdown it's oppening up because the select its on the bottom edge of the page)

I have read about jquery having issues to calculate offsets of elements that had a css transformation, and tried every workaround and tried to comment every transform word in my code... no results.

I've found that the issue is fixed when I give my html body enough height to make it scroll (I don't want that). Do you guys have some ideas? (see my code bellow):

HTML:

```
    <div style="margin-left:50px;width:250px; float: left;">
    <select name="marca" id="marca" data-placeholder="Marca"
        class="select2" tabindex="15">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option class="response" value="ALCATEL" text="Alcatel">Alcatel</option>
        <option class="response" value="APPLE" text="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option class="response" value="AVVIO" text="Avvio Full">Avvio
            Full</option>
        <option class="response" value="ENSPIRE" text="Cellon Enspire">Cellon
            Enspire</option>
        <option class="response" value="ERIC" text="Ericsson">Ericsson</option>
        <option class="response" value="HTC" text="High Tech Computer ">High
            Tech Computer</option>
        <option class="response" value="HUAWEI" text="Huawei">Huawei</option>
        <option class="response" value="IMAC" text="Imac">Imac</option>
        <option class="response" value="LG" text="Lg">Lg</option>
        <option class="response" value="M4TEL" text="M4tel">M4tel</option>
        <option class="response" value="MOTO" text="Motorola">Motorola</option>
        <option class="response" value="NOKI" text="Nokia">Nokia</option>
        <option class="response" value="PALM" text="Palmone Modelo">Palmone
            Modelo</option>
        <option class="response" value="PACO" text="Pantech Co., Ltd">Pantech
            Co., Ltd</option>
        <option class="response" value="PCD"
            text="Personal Communication Device">Personal
            Communication Device</option>
        <option class="response" value="SAGEM" text="Sagem">Sagem</option>
        <option class="response" value="SAMS" text="Samsung">Samsung</option>
        <option class="response" value="SWT"
            text="Servicell Wireless Technologie">Servicell Wireless
            Technologie</option>
        <option class="response" value="SIWI" text="Sierra Wireless">Sierra
            Wireless</option>
        <option class="response" value="SKTE" text="Sk  Teletec Co.,ltd">Sk
            Teletec Co.,ltd</option>
        <option class="response" value="TELU" text="Telular">Telular</option>
        <option class="response" value="VERYKOOL" text="Verykool">Verykool</option>
        <option class="response" value="VKMOB" text="Vk Mobile">Vk
            Mobile</option>
        <option class="response" value="ZONDA" text="Zonda">Zonda</option>
        <option class="response" value="ZTE" text="Zte Corporation">Zte
            Corporation</option>
    </select>
        </div>
```

The select CSS:

```
    #disponibilidadForm select {
    width: 245px;
    }

#modelo,#marca {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.select2-offscreen,.select2-offscreen:focus {
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    outline: 0;
    left: 0px;
}

user agent stylesheetkeygen,select,select[size="0"],select[size="1"] {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

user agent stylesheetselect {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    white-space: pre;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: default;
}

user agent stylesheetkeygen,select {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

user agent stylesheetinput,textarea,keygen,select,button,isindex {
    margin: 0em;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
}

user agent stylesheetinput,textarea,keygen,select,button,isindex,meter,progress
    {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}

Inherited from div.float_left
    .float_left {
    text-align: left;
}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
    {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}

Inherited from form#disponibilidadForm
    html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
    {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}

Inherited from div.formulario.float_right
    .float_right {
    text-align: left;
}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
    {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}

Inherited from div
    html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
    {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}

Inherited from div.contenido
    html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
    {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}

Inherited from body
    body {
    line-height: 1;
}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
    {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}

Inherited from html
    html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
    {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the css property "overflow: scroll;" to the html body fixed the position of the dropdown, and the page doesn't get scrolled

Comment: what do you mean by this ? can you provide better details on this ? thanks.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. Thank you!